# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strip!' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It seems I'm running into this error when I insert more than 100,000 records. I know it can support way more than that. The error is below and the code for the related classes.

```
2015-07-01 08:14:24.512:INFO:/:Started GET "/search?type=digital_object" for 129.118.15.44 at 2015-07-01 08:14:24 -0500|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.512:INFO:/:Processing by SearchController#search as HTML|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.512:INFO:/:  Parameters: {"type"=>"digital_object"}|
Jul 01, 2015 8:14:24 AM org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore execute
INFO: [collection1] webapp= path=/select params={facet=true&sort=title_sort+asc&facet.limit=100&qf=four_part_id^3+title^2+finding_aid_filing_title^2+fullrecord&wt=json&rows=10&defType=edismax&pf=four_part_id^4&start=0&q=*:*&facet.field=repository&facet.field=primary_type&facet.field=subjects&facet.field=source&facet.field=linked_agent_roles&fq=types:("digital_object")&fq=-exclude_by_default:true&fq=publish:true} hits=203799 status=0 QTime=15 
2015-07-01 08:14:24.590:INFO:/:  Rendered G:/archivesspace/plugins/vva/public/views/search/_components_switch.html.erb (15.0ms)|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.590:INFO:/:  Rendered search/_filter.html.erb (0.0ms)|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.606:INFO:/:  Rendered search/_pagination_summary.html.erb (16.0ms)|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.637:INFO:/:  Rendered search/_inline_results.html.erb (47.0ms)|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.637:INFO:/:  Rendered search/results.html.erb within layouts/application (62.0ms)|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.653:INFO:/:Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 141.0ms|
2015-07-01 08:14:24.653:INFO:/:|ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `strip!' for nil:NilClass):|    
17:           <% elsif result["primary_type"] === "repository" %>|    
18:             <%= link_to result['title'], :controller => :search, :action => :repository, :repo_id => id %>|    
19:           <% else %>|    
20:             <%= link_to title_or_finding_aid_filing_title( result )  , :controller => :records, :action => result["primary_type"], :id => id, :repo_id => repo_id %>|    
21:           <% end %>|    
22:         </h3>|    
23:         <div class="result-summary">|  app/helpers/application_helper.rb:22:in `title_or_finding_aid_filing_title'|  
app/views/search/_inline_results.html.erb:20:in `_app_views_search__inline_results_html_erb___996910774_15116'| 
app/views/search/_inline_results.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_search__inline_results_html_erb___996910774_15116'|  
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:134:in `render_aspace_partial'|  
app/views/search/results.html.erb:13:in `_app_views_search_results_html_erb__332589766_15048'|  
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:21:in `search'|  
app/controllers/search_controller.rb:20:in `search'|||
```

_inline_results.html.erb

```
<div class="search-results">
<% if search_data.results? %>
  <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "search/pagination_summary", :locals => {:search_data => search_data} %>
  <ul class="results-list">
    <% search_data['results'].each do |result| %>
      <%
         id = JSONModel(result["primary_type"]).id_for(result['uri'])
         repo_id = JSONModel(:repository).id_for(JSONModel.repository_for(result['uri']),{}, true)
      %>
      <li class="result">
        <h3>
          <%= icon_for result["primary_type"] %>
          <% if result["primary_type"] === "subject" %>
            <%= link_to result["title"], {"filter_term" => search_data.facet_query_string("subjects", result["title"])} %>
          <% elsif ["agent_person", "agent_software", "agent_family", "agent_corporate_entity"].include?(result["primary_type"]) %>
            <%= link_to result['title'], :controller => :records, :action => :agent, :id => id, :agent_type => result["primary_type"] %>
          <% elsif result["primary_type"] === "repository" %>
            <%= link_to result['title'], :controller => :search, :action => :repository, :repo_id => id %>
          <% else %>
            <%= link_to title_or_finding_aid_filing_title( result )  , :controller => :records, :action => result["primary_type"], :id => id, :repo_id => repo_id %>
          <% end %>
        </h3>
        <div class="result-summary">
          <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "search/result_summary_#{result["primary_type"]}", :locals => {:obj => result} %>
        </div>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  <%= render_aspace_partial :partial => "search/pagination", :locals => {:search_data => search_data} %>
<% else %>
  <p class="alert alert-info">
    <%= I18n.t("search_results.no_results") %></em>.
  </p>
<% end %>
</div>
```

search_controller.rb

```
require 'advanced_query_builder'

class SearchController < ApplicationController

  DETAIL_TYPES = ['accession', 'resource', 'archival_object', 'digital_object',
                  'digital_object_component', 'classification',
                  'agent_person', 'agent_family', 'agent_software', 'agent_corporate_entity']

  VIEWABLE_TYPES = ['agent', 'repository', 'subject'] + DETAIL_TYPES

  FACETS = ["repository", "primary_type", "subjects", "source", "linked_agent_roles"]


  def search
    set_search_criteria

    @search_data = Search.all(@criteria, @repositories)
    @term_map = params[:term_map] ? ASUtils.json_parse(params[:term_map]) : {}

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render "search/results" }
      format.js { render_aspace_partial :partial => "search/inline_results", :content_type => "text/html", :locals => {:search_data => @search_data} }
    end
  end

  def advanced_search
    set_advanced_search_criteria

    @search_data = Search.all(@criteria, @repositories)

    render "search/results"
  end

  def repository
    set_search_criteria

    if params[:repo_id].blank?
      @search_data = Search.all(@criteria.merge({"facet[]" => [], "type[]" => ["repository"]}), {})

      return render "search/results"
    end

    @repository = @repositories.select{|repo| JSONModel(:repository).id_for(repo.uri).to_s === params[:repo_id]}.first

    @breadcrumbs = [
      [@repository['repo_code'], url_for(:controller => :search, :action => :repository, :id => @repository.id), "repository"]
    ]

    @search_data = Search.repo(@repository.id, @criteria, @repositories)

    render "search/results"
  end


  private

  def set_search_criteria
    @criteria = params.select{|k,v|
      ["page", "q", "type", "sort",
       "filter_term", "root_record", "format"].include?(k) and not v.blank?
    }

    @criteria["page"] ||= 1
    @criteria["sort"] = "title_sort asc" unless @criteria["sort"] or @criteria["q"] or params["advanced"].present?

    if @criteria["filter_term"]
      @criteria["filter_term[]"] = Array(@criteria["filter_term"]).reject{|v| v.blank?}
      @criteria.delete("filter_term")
    end

    if params[:type].blank?
      @criteria['type[]'] = DETAIL_TYPES
    else
      @criteria['type[]'] = Array(params[:type]).keep_if {|t| VIEWABLE_TYPES.include?(t)}
      @criteria.delete("type")
    end

    @criteria['exclude[]'] = params[:exclude] if not params[:exclude].blank?
    @criteria['facet[]'] = FACETS
  end


  def set_advanced_search_criteria
    set_search_criteria

    terms = (0..2).collect{|i|
      term = search_term(i)

      if term and term["op"] === "NOT"
        term["op"] = "AND"
        term["negated"] = true
      end

      term
    }.compact

    if not terms.empty?
      @criteria["aq"] = AdvancedQueryBuilder.new(terms, :public).build_query.to_json
      @criteria['facet[]'] = FACETS
    end
  end

  def search_term(i)
    if not params["v#{i}"].blank?
      { "field" => params["f#{i}"], "value" => params["v#{i}"], "op" => params["op#{i}"], "type" => "text" }
    end
  end

end
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def include_theme_css
    css = ""
    css += stylesheet_link_tag("themes/#{ArchivesSpacePublic::Application.config.public_theme}/bootstrap", :media => "all")
    css += stylesheet_link_tag("themes/#{ArchivesSpacePublic::Application.config.public_theme}/application", :media => "all")
    css.html_safe
  end

  def set_title(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def title_or_finding_aid_filing_title(resource)
    if resource["finding_aid_filing_title"] && !resource["finding_aid_filing_title"].nil? && resource["finding_aid_filing_title"].length > 0
      title = resource["finding_aid_filing_title"]
    elsif resource["title"] && !resource["title"].nil?
      title = resource["title"]
    else
      title = resource["display_string"]
    end
    MixedContentParser::parse(title, url_for(:root))


  end

  def icon_for(type)
    "<span class='icon-#{type}' title='#{I18n.t("#{type}._singular")}'></span>".html_safe
  end

  def label_and_value(label, value)
    return if value.blank?

    label = content_tag(:dt, label)
    value = content_tag(:dd, value)

    label + value
  end

  def i18n_enum(jsonmodel_type, property, value)
    return if value.blank?

    property_defn = JSONModel(jsonmodel_type).schema["properties"][property]

    return if property_defn.nil?

    if property_defn.has_key? "dynamic_enum"
      enum_key = property_defn["dynamic_enum"]
      #return "enumerations.#{enum_key}.#{value}"
      I18n.t("enumerations.#{enum_key}.#{value}", :default => value)
    else
      I18n.t("#{jsonmodel_type}.#{property}_#{value}", :default => value) 
    end
  end

  def params_for_search(opts = {})
    search_params = {
      :controller => :search,
      :action => :search
    }

    search_params["filter_term"] = Array(opts["filter_term"] || params["filter_term"]).clone
    search_params["filter_term"].concat(Array(opts["add_filter_term"])) if opts["add_filter_term"]
    search_params["filter_term"] = search_params["filter_term"].reject{|f| Array(opts["remove_filter_term"]).include?(f)} if opts["remove_filter_term"]

    search_params["sort"] = opts["sort"] || params["sort"]

    search_params["q"] = opts["q"] || params["q"]

    search_params["format"] = params["format"]
    search_params["root_record"] = params["root_record"]
    search_params["agent_type"] = params["agent_type"]

    search_params["page"] = opts["page"] || params["page"] || 1

    if opts["type"] && opts["type"].kind_of?(Array)
      search_params["type"] = opts["type"]
    else
      search_params["type"] = opts["type"] || params["type"]
    end

    search_params["term_map"] = params["term_map"]

    # retain any advanced search params
    advanced = (opts["advanced"] || params["advanced"])
    search_params["advanced"] = advanced.blank? || advanced === 'false' ? false : true
    search_params[:action] = :advanced_search if search_params["advanced"]

    (0..2).each do |i|
      search_params["v#{i}"] = params["v#{i}"]
      search_params["f#{i}"] = params["f#{i}"]
      search_params["op#{i}"] = params["op#{i}"]
    end

    search_params.reject{|k,v| k.blank? or v.blank?}
  end

  def set_title_for_search
    title =  I18n.t("actions.search")

    if @search_data
      if params[:type] && !@search_data.types.blank?
        title = "#{I18n.t("search_results.searching")} #{@search_data.types.join(", ")}"
      end

      facets_to_display = []

      if @search_data.query?
        facets_to_display << @search_data.facet_label_for_query
      end

      if @search_data.filtered_terms?
        facets_to_display << @search_data[:criteria]["filter_term[]"].collect{|filter_term| @search_data.facet_label_for_filter(filter_term)}
      end

      if facets_to_display.length > 0
        title += " | #{facets_to_display.join(", ")}"
      end
    end

    set_title(title)
  end

  def truncate(string, length = 50, trailing = '&hellip;')
    return string if string.length < length

    "#{string[0..50]}#{trailing}".html_safe
  end


  # See: ApplicationController#render_aspace_partial
  def render_aspace_partial(args)
    defaults = {:formats => [:html], :handlers => [:erb]}
    return render(defaults.merge(args))
  end

  def proxy_localhost?
    AppConfig[:frontend_proxy_url] =~ /localhost/
  end

end
```

Comment: I would suggest truncating your post, removing messages in the log, or even bits of code, that do not relate to the problem at hand. Your files are quite long, and may even be better in a gist or pastebin.

Comment: Furthermore, Remember that you can still add logger statements in the view and controller! This will help determining whether objects are nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it figured out. Looks like some of the data imported had blank titles "". By updating them it was able to work.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your _inline_results.html.erb...

```
<% elsif result["primary_type"] === "repository" %>
        <%= link_to result['title'], :controller => :search, :action => :repository, :repo_id => id %>
```

the error is that the result['title'] is nil. so, add this line of code....

```
<% elsif result["primary_type"] === "repository" %>
  <% if !result['title'].blank? %>        
    <%= link_to result['title'], :controller => :search, :action => :repository, :repo_id => id %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem.  I still get the same error.